# Jmeter Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, jmeter, load-testing

I have a .Net web application where the users can take a test (the test consists of series of Question and Answers)

I tried to do a load test on my application for 1500 threads using Jmeter.
All the users were able to log into the application using Username and Password.
But when they started the test, all the users got stuck on the first Question.

The errors showing in JMeter was:

```
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException
```

All at the first question.

The server logs shows that the connection to the SQL server was down.

I think the Sql Server is able to handle maximum of 32767 concurrent connections.

How can I handle the load of 1500 users on my .Net application and the SQL server?

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [ASP.NET Thread Usage on IIS 7.5, IIS 7.0, and IIS 6.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tmarq/2007/07/20/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-5-iis-7-0-and-iis-6-0/) the default maximum number of concurrent connections is 12 per CPU so you might want to create `MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU` registry key under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET\your-ASP-version` and set the number of connections to the desired amount.

You can also try to identify the maximum number of users the server can support by starting with 1 and [gradually](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide/) increasing the load to 1500 at the same time looking into ASP, SQL and Windows metrics using [Windows Performance Monitor](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-performance-monitor-windows-10), my expectation is that there is nothing with SQL server, the error is rather on JMeter or on IIS side.